# How to print Product collection mysql query in magento2

Tags: database, magento2.3, product-sorting

In my product page Price sorting not works properly. So i need to know which field value consider for sorting ? the issue occurs in configurable products.How do I print the actual MySQL code that gets executed?

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?

Comment: Magneto 2.3/ Community Version

Comment: Please check this issue as same I was also dealing with https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/36a3c26bd7492f4638fe02085156d2510687a34a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a product collection like this:

```
//$collection is instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
                'status', array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            );
```

Then you can simple get sql query by this:

```
echo $collection->getSelect();
```

or

you can add this to the `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` file: (File location would depend on your theme)

```
echo $_productCollection->getSelect();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this type code that is example of how to print mysql query.

```
    <?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productCollections = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collections = $productCollections->create();
    $collections->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    echo $collections->getSelect()->__toString();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way, echo your collection with getSelect function.

Here it is

```
echo $collection->getSelect();
```